# i want add conditional for add category in wordpress

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

i have marketplace plugin 
when the seller want add product 
first he will choose category 
i want change this code to 
for example i have 2 main category ( A - B ) 
and i have ( C - D - E ) under A
and i have ( F - G - H ) under B
this my code

```
    <td>

                                        <label for="mp_seller_product_categories">Produkt kategorier</label>

                                </td>

                                <td>

                                        <?php

                                        $allowed_cat = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'wkmp_seller_allowed_categories', true);

                                        if (! $allowed_cat) {
                                                $allowed_categories = get_option('wkmp_seller_allowed_categories');
                                        } else {
                                                $allowed_categories = $allowed_cat;
                                        }

                                        require 'class-taxonomy-filter.php';

                                        $product_categories = wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                                                'show_option_none' => __( '', 'marketplace' ),
                                                'hierarchical'     => 1,
                                                'hide_empty'       => 0,
                                                'name'             => 'product_cate[]',
                                                'id'               => 'mp_seller_product_categories',
                                                'taxonomy'         => 'product_cat',
                                                'title_li'         => '',
                                                'orderby'                  => 'name',
                                                'order'                      => 'ASC',
                                                'class'            => '',
                                                'exclude'          => '',
                                                'selected'         => array(),
                                                'echo'             => 0,
                                                'value_field'        => 'slug',
                                                'walker'                     => new MpProductCategoryTree($allowed_categories)
                                        ) );

                                        echo str_replace( '<select', '<select style="width: 50%;" data-placeholder="'.__( 'Choose category(s)', 'marketplace' ).'" multiple="multiple" ', $product_categories );

                                        ?>

                                </td>
```

i want change to

first seller will choose A or B
if choose A 
he can choose ( C or D or E )
else he choose B
he can Choose ( F or G or H )

and i don't want the code take category from wordpress system 
i want write the category in code

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then something like this might do the trick.

```
// html markup for the selects
<select name="main_cat">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<select name="sub_cat_for_A" class="sub-cat-select hidden">
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>

<select name="sub_cat_for_B" class="sub-cat-select hidden">
    <option value="F">F</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
    <option value="H">H</option>
</select>
```

If you change your mind and want to use a taxonomy from WordPress, you can change the markup to this,

```
<?php
$main_categories = array();
$sub_categories = array();
$cats = get_terms(array(
  'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy',
));

if ( $cats && ! is_wp_error( $cats ) ) {
  foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
    if ( $cat->parent ) {
      $sub_categories[$cat->parent][$cat->term_id] = $cat->name;
    } else {
      $main_categories[$cat->term_id] = $cat->name;
    }
  }
}
?>

<select name="main_cat">
  <?php foreach ( $main_categories as $id => $name ) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<?php foreach ( $sub_categories as $main_cat_id => $sub_category_options ) : ?>
  <select name="<?php echo "sub_cat_for_{$main_cat_id}" ?>" class="sub-cat-select hidden">
    <?php foreach ( $sub_category_options as $id => $name ) : ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then you just need some jQuery (vanilla javascript could be used also) to watch changes on the main select and to show the related sub-select.

```
jQuery(document).on('ready',function($){
  $('select[name="main_cat"]').on('change',function(event){
    var selectedMainCatId = $(this).value();
    // hide other sub cat selects
    $('.sub-cat-select').addClass('hidden');
    // show correct sub cat select
    $('select[name="sub_cat_for_'+selectedMainCatId+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
  });  
});
```

There might be room for improvement on the jQuery example, but I'm sure you'll get the basic principle from it.

Comment: actuality i not understand second one ( php code )
but if i want use the first one 
but when seller choose for example C 
how will the product be in this category ??
i dont know how must use  jQuery or where i must write it

Comment: The second example first gets all the terms from a custom taxonomy and then sorts the results in to two arrays. It then creates similar html markup as in the first example, but automatically uses the term ID's as option values.

Comment: How the product gets associated with the selected category depends on how the product actually gets added to your site. It could be a form that gets posted or an ajax request.

Comment: Scripts can be added to your site either by printing them with php or with a scripts.js file that is added to the site with wp_enqueue_script.

Comment: By the way, is this a plugin that you're developing yourself or a plugin that you've downloaded from somewhere and you're trying to modify? If you're trying to modify a downloaded plugin, please contact the plugin author for support. If the plugin author won't help you and you don't know how to make edits yourself, please consider hiring a developer to do the work for you.